# Implementing searchBarSearchButtonClicked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How would I implement the searchBarSearchButtonClicked method? I am trying to pass the value of the search bar when the searchBarSearchButtonClicked to a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    yourlabel.text = searchBar.text;

    // DO what ever you want


  }
```

Comment: Where would I place the call for this function [self searchBar]?

Comment: no need to place the function for searchbar, you drag the UISearchbar in xib and connect it.Also connect the delegates. declare the searchbar in .h, use the above delegate. Thats it..!!

Comment: you are welcome bro, this is absolutely a basic thing, so before you post something, try to search. Apple documentation contains most of the things. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
  _myLabel.text = searchBar.text;
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Where would I place the call for this function `[self searchBar]`?